# Problem opening JP2 image using GDAL (interaction of -stats and -hist flags)

Tags: gdal, statistics, jpeg-2000, sentinel-2, histogram

I came across unexpected GDAL behaviour while working with Sentinel-2 data granules. The Sentinel data should have values between `0` and `10000` when opened correctly.

However, I have noticed that when working with the data, pixel values above 10000 are retrieved. After doing some digging, I found this post which points to similar problems in ESA's Snap software. [They refer to a bug in the OpenJpeg library](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/the-quantification-value-has-a-true-value-dn-to-toa-reflectance/1220/46).

This could be the problem in my case as well, as my GDAL binaries use JP2OpenJPEG in the background (see below).

The strange behavior is the following: The values are in the expected range when using the `gdalinfo -hist` command, but are wrong when using `gdalinfo -hist -stats`.

I also get values above 10000 when using the GDAL c-api directly.

My questions are

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a way to open such jp2 images with 15bpp correctly in GDAL?

Here is an example and a link to the corresponding file:

http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/48/M/WA/2016/6/29/0/B11.jp2

```
$ gdalinfo B11.jp2 -hist
Band 1 Block=640x640 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
  256 buckets from -15.7549 to 8050.75:
  23286152 2037325 ... 11251 
  Overviews: 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686, 343x343
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=8035
    STATISTICS_MEAN=274.9824
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=944.69220833573
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
    NBITS=15

$ rm B11.jp2.aux.xml
$ gdalinfo B11.jp2 -hist -stats
Band 1 Block=640x640 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=12356.000, Mean=272.236, StdDev=901.137
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
  256 buckets from -24.2275 to 12380.2:
  23286928 2372470 ... 0 0 1 0 1 
  Overviews: 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686, 343x343
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=12356
    STATISTICS_MEAN=272.236306847
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=901.13698170459
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
    NBITS=15
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.06 with the Ubuntugis gdal version

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25

$ gdalinfo --formats | grep JP2
JP2OpenJPEG -raster,vector- (rwv): JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the band values above 10'000 make sense after all.

10k is the number that represents 100% reflectance in the data. That's why I thought that the values should be bound by this number, but they are not.

Reflectances can be higher than 100%, see [the answer of a related question on the step forum](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/toa-range-in-sentinel-2-images-between-0-an-1/3168).

I think the difference in the output of GDAL might be related to approximate vs excact calculations of the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

A test with GDAL 2.3-dev and OpenJPEG driver gives different result with -stats:

```
Band 1 Block=640x640 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=12356.000, Mean=272.236, StdDev=901.137
  Overviews: 2745x2745, 1372x1372, 686x686, 343x343
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=12356
    STATISTICS_MEAN=272.236306847
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=901.13698170459
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
    NBITS=15
```

I am getting also the same result with Kakadu driver:

```
Driver: JP2KAK/JPEG-2000 (based on Kakadu v7.3.2)
Files: b11.jp2
...
Metadata:
  STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=12356
  STATISTICS_MEAN=272.236306847
  STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
  STATISTICS_STDDEV=901.13698170459
```

Are you sure that the file does not contain values higher than 10000? With which method have you confirmed it?

Comment: Thanks for checking the numbers @user30184, your answer made me doubt my assumption of the 10k value bound (see answer below). It turns out that I was wrong on that, so thanks for your help on this!